# AWK printing front of the line rather than end of the line

Tags: html, awk, carriage-return

Hi Trying to insert `<br>` at the end of command output with awk but it is printing at the beginning

My command and expected output:
`cat cmd.out |awk ' {printf $0"<br>\n" }'`
`Getting addresses from network interface table...<br> Getting addresses from sitelist...<br>`

But actual output is:
`<br>ing addresses from network interface table... <br>ing addresses from sitelist...`

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: looks like your input file contains windows/dos line endings (`\r\n`); easy solution would be to run `dos2unix cmd.out` (removes `\r` from file so only have to run once after file is created/populated) before running your code; alternatives would be to use `tr -d '\r'`, or add code to your `awk` script to remove the `\r` characters

Comment: This should help: `dos2unix <cmd.out | awk ' {printf $0"<br>\n" }'`

Comment: Never do `printf $0` (or $anything) as it'll fail when your input contains printf formatting characters like `%s`. Use `printf "%s<br>\n", $0` instead of `printf $0"<br>\n"`